# make my object fly in box2d AS3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, object, box2d

just to the main problem, since in box2d the object will automatically drop to the bottom, then i want to create my object flying and stay with the same height.

and here is my code that i got from some web:

```
gravityOffset.Multiply(-body.GetMass());
body.ApplyForce(gravityOffset, body.GetWorldCenter());
```

my object is fly but its fly away and never come back like a rocket.

i modified the code like this :

```
gravityOffset.x = 0;
gravityOffset.y = 0;
body.ApplyForce(gravityOffset, body.GetWorldCenter());
```

but its still fly to up slowly..

and when the fly time is over, i want to make it falling again.
any one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just fire a rocket into the air and have it come back down then:

```
body.ApplyImpulse(velocity,body.GetWorldCenter());
```

However, if you are wanting more control over the rocket, rather than just fire and forget then it gets a bit harder.

That being the case I would then probably use some [steering behaviours](http://books.google.com.au/books?id=gDLpyWtFacYC&pg=PA85&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false) and use the seek function to have it move towards a vector (you can then keep moving this vector to wherever to get the rocket to follow it).

Comment: the movement that i want is like this.
http://imageshack.us/f/837/30162489.jpg/

the object just move to the right, and also i want to add cloud, so i need code how to make this cloud didn't fall..

Comment: so the rocket follows the blue trajectory? and the cloud follows the green trajectory?

Comment: the condition is the body follow the blue one, but what i want is follow the green one. after try much another method, i use this. 

gravityOffset.y = -body.GetLinearVelocity().y;
body.ApplyForce(gravityOffset , body.GetWorldCenter() );

while gravityOffset is b2vec2 variable and its works, and now i must make it fall with the same speed/force as it speed while it go up..
any suggestion?